print statement within ZStack
I'm trying to debug a SwiftUI app with some print statements. I'm getting an index out of bounds error on the 'tapCards[i]'. I did step through the code in the debugger which was somewhat helpful, but I also would like to see some info in the standard output. Here's my ZStack:
            ZStack // ZStack for card(s) being played
            {
                print("BEGIN ZStack for tapCards");
                let ct : Int = model.tapCards.count
                let emp : Bool = model.tapCards.isEmpty
                if model.tapCards.isEmpty
                {
                    print("... tapCards is EMPTY, showing 'back'")
                    Image("back").border(Color.black, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
                else
                {
                    print("... tapCards is NOT EMPTY, showing $ct in stack")
                    ForEach(0..<model.tapCards.count, id: \.self)
                    { i in
                        print("... ... BEGIN card at index $i")
                        let cardNumber : Int = model.tapCards[i]
                        let tapCardImgName = String (format: "%03i", model.tapCards[i])
                        Image(model.tapCards.count == 0 ? "back" : tapCardImgName)
                            .border(Color.black, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .offset(x: CGFloat(i) * 10.0,
                                    y: CGFloat(i) * 10.0)
                        print("... ... END card at index $i")
                    }
                }
                print("END ZStack for tapCards")
            } // ZStack for card(s) being played

It wont build because of the first print statement.  This is the error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'
I commented it out and then of course the next print statement gave that error.
So are print statements not allowed in ZStacks? or Views in general?
Note: I have over 30 years of software development experience, mostly with C, C++, and Java. SwiftUI is new for me.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

let _ = print("")

Note than ranges and using self as an id are considered unsafe with SwiftUI

@loremipsum I had no idea - why is it unsafe?

Watch "Demystify SwiftUI" it is very informative.
